# Convert box-and-arrow (text) markup to an image

Tags: diagramming

Sometimes, the quickest way to transcribe box-and-arrow diagrams on a computer is to use plain text markup. Unfortunately, this markup can be unreadable by people who aren't familiar with its syntax.

**Is there a way to convert box-and-arrow markup into an image (png or svg)**-- sort of like one would compile a LaTeX document or equation?

What I am envisioning is something that will take syntax like `A->B->C` and create an image with three boxes that connects A to B to C.

Comment: This question isn't a very good fit for a Q&A site such as this because it's a request for a product name, which means there's no one best answer (http://bubbl.us, http://gliffy.com, and http://mindmeister.com would all fit this description) and classification of which answers are "better" changes over time.  If you change your question to instead ask what to take into account when selecting such task flow software, it would be a better fit.

Comment: @3nafish I don't understand. As far as I'm aware, there is only one website that does this and thus there is **only one correct answer**. None of the websites you mention fit the description I gave, as they don't embed UML within a URL.

Comment: This really is a tools request, and as such *Off Topic* for this site.

Comment: @BennySkogberg thanks, i didn't know

Comment: @BennySkogberg I've edited to try and be more general, but if it's still inappropriate, feel free to delete.

Comment: @Jeff I'm glad you've made the effort, but this is still implementation request, not what would make the best **User Experience**. Take a look at the [faq](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an online service called [yUML.me](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/samples) that can do this. It is good for small diagrams, but can be cumbersome for large ones.

The service allows you to embed your syntax in a URL, which can generate a variety of output image formats.

An example from their website is the URL `http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/[Wages]^-[Salaried], [Wages]^-[Contractor]`, which results in this:

[image: http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/[Wages]%5E-[Salaried],%20[Wages]%5E-[Contractor]]